# Setting the value of an <input> dropdown in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a HTML page containing a form with an  tag. I want to set the value of the drop down in this tag using Selenium.

This is how I retrieve the input element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
```

I tried to set the value using `select_month.send_keys("09")` but this is not accepted by the web page when I try to submit the form so I need to find another method.

EDIT: Here is the HTML of the form, I have ensured that it is the right element in my x-path:

```
<input autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" class="ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)" placeholder="Select month" ng-model="$select.search" ng-hide="!$select.searchEnabled || ($select.selected &amp;&amp; !$select.open)" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" type="text">
```

Comment: is there any other input elements at same level? can you try with firebug to ensure element location is correct.

Comment: I have ensured that the Xpath is correct.

Comment: How about `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Select month']")`?

Comment: Ok, that works as well for locating the element, but does not solve my dropdown problem.

Comment: dropdown? where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around a bit and incorporating the better practice presented by alecxe, this solution worked...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Select month']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '09')]").click()
```